# Tabla con celdas combinadas

Tags: html, tablas

Me ayuda a crear la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No manejo bien celdas combinadas y llego hasta aquí:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid">
    
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">ELEMENTOS DE UN COMPUTADOR</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Tipos de Periféricos</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Periférico</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid" rowspan="1">Características</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Código</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con un [Editor WYSIWYG](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) o con generadores online, por ejemplo: https://tabletag.net/

Comment: Debes usar colspan y rowspan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combinando celdas con `rowspan` y `colspan`, podrás resolverlo:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid; text-align:center;">
    
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid" colspan="6">ELEMENTOS DE UN COMPUTADOR</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid" rowspan="2">Tipos de Periféricos</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid" rowspan="2">Periférico</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid" colspan="4">Características</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Código</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Imagen</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Color</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Puerto de entrada</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid" rowspan="3">Entrada</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Mouse</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Teclado</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Mando consola</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid" rowspan="3">Salida</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Monitor</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Parlantes</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">Impresora</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid" colspan="6">Curso - Paralelo - ...</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Continúa tú y, si tienes alguna duda, déjala en los comentarios